# Paypal IPN white blank

Tags: php, paypal

I am having a problem with `paypal` ipn script.

If I test it with sandbox then it works but when I use `paypal` then it just shows the white page and not even the error message.

I need to get item_number from script. Tried some thing but no success.
Script is from the `paypal` page. I am just out of ideas. First time trying `paypal` payment system.

Code:

```
<?php
    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
    $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
    $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

    $ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
    if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    $tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
    $res = trim(end($tokens));
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    echo "works";

    } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    echo "error";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Check your web server log files.

Comment: it says GET  but rm is set to 2
[03/Feb/2015:19:44:35 +0200] "GET /ipn?tx=8SP91207X02266842&st=Completed&amt=10%2e85&cc=EUR&cm=&item_number=54d108e4045e3 HTTP/1.1" 200 424 "-"

[03/Feb/2015:19:44:41 +0200] "POST /home HTTP/1.0" 200 6518 "-" "PayPal IPN ( https://www.paypal.com/ipn )"

Comment: Well you are passing in query parameters and not a post body. You should read up in how the HTTP protocol works.

Comment: How are you testing?  You mention that you're getting a blank white page, but you shouldn't be seeing anything in the browser unless you've setup your own simulator.

Comment: tested with payment from another paypal account. Recived money but script fails

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to find solution and share it to others. I used this script: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php

Changed this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
```

To this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close', 'User-Agent: company-name'));
```

This is why it doesn't work. Paypal have made some kind of update but haven't update example script. Every thing is working now.